# jquery compatibility problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

Why does the following work in firefox but not in IE?

```
            $("#bCompare").bind("click", function(e){
                $("img[src='s1.gif']").each(function (i) {
                    $("#cSelected").append("<div class='cHolder'></div>");
                });
            });
```

UPDATE 1: A commenter mentioned I haven't put in enough information, although i'm not sure what more is needed. The above code checks for the number of images with the src s1.gif. It then runs a loop inserting a div of the class cHolder into the div cSelected. The number cHolders added depends on the number of s1.gif images.

There are no error messages in either browser. Firefox 3.5 and IE 7

UPDATE 2: I've narrowed it down to a problem in the "each" method. Outside the loop it works fine in both. Is there any way to get around this? Thanks.

Comment: dude, you need to post more detail before your question gets closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Which version of IE? My guess is the version you're using is choking on the `img[src='s1.gif']` selector (support for this type of selector can be spotty across browsers), but without more details, can't really say.

Comment: not work in what way? what error message do you see? is this all the relevant code?

Comment: @pygorex jquery does not use browser's css selector to do such selections. I believe it uses Sizzle, by the dojo foundation.

Comment: theres no error, nothing happens

Comment: Are you sure nothing happens? Inserting an empty div at the end of an element might have no visible effect on the page. Did you try checking with firebug or the developer tools in IE or Chrome.

Comment: @unknown It would help if you tell us what you are trying to do. In this case, I presume you are appending a `div.cHolder` to `#cSelected` for each `img[src='s1.gif']` on the page, for whatever reason you have.

Comment: I've tried using the alert function, nothing inside the each method is called in IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've run into is actually really interesting.  I started with your code, and the results are quite confusing.  The `src='s1.gif'` selector works fine in Firefox and IE8, but not in IE7 or IE6.  I ended up with a test document to figure out this selector:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
</script>

<img id="foo" src="foo.png"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('# images: ' + $('img').length + ', ' + 'Src: "' + $('#foo').attr('src') + '", Num of imgs selected by src: ' + $("img[src='foo.png']").length);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So assuming you have an image file called "foo.png" in the same directory as this test document, you get the following alerts in FF3.5, IE8, IE7, and IE6 respectively:

```
# images: 1, "foo.png", Num of images selected by src: 1
# images: 1, "foo.png", Num of images selected by src: 1
# images: 1, "foo.png", Num of images selected by src: 0
# images: 1, "foo.png", Num of images selected by src: 0
```

So the selector `$("img[src='foo.png']")` clearly doesn't find the image properly in IE6 and 7, despite the `src` being reported correctly by the alert.  If you change the selector src to the *full path* to the image (`$("img[src='http://whatever/foo.png']")`), you get the opposite results.  It's found in IE6/7, but not in IE8 or FF.

Very weird.  The `src` must be represented differently in the DOM somehow in these browsers, but not accounted for properly by JQuery.

Gaby actually posted an answer that was on the right track, but then he deleted it.  If you use a selector with a `$` sign, like `img[src$='foo.png']`, it appears to work in all 4 of these browsers, as it matches the `foo.png` on the end of the attribute value.

I would suggest you go with that method.

Comment: Drat, I was going to suggest `$` selector as well. Good work, +1.

Comment: Np, I use JQuery for my job, so I actually had a vested interest in figuring it out.  I didn't find much on Google about it, I'm wondering now whether it's worth submitting to the JQuery folks for perusal.

Answer (score 1):

Try to narrow down the problem a little. It could be one of (at least) three things:

- the handler doesn't bind or never gets called. Add an `alert` in your outer function to find out.
- The img selector is not giving you the images you want. Add another `alert` or put out a counter somewhere.
- The div is really being created but you don't see it due to, perhaps, something unexpected happening with how IE handles your `cHolder` class.

Without a complete example to look at, that's probably about the best we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm not entirely sure, but...

...try:

```
$("img[src=s1.gif]")
```

If not, post the output of

```
alert( $("img[src='s1.gif']").length );
```

and

```
alert( $("img[src='s1.gif']").length );
```

when run in firefox and IE

Comment: Removing the quotes around an attribute value that has a `.` in it will break that selector.